# Select2 v4 in jqGrid edit modal window issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, jquery-select2-4

I know issue with jQueryUI modal window and Select2. I'm using this fix https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1246#issuecomment-71710835. But currently I'm trying to integrate Select2 with jqGrid and its edit modal window and I noticed that input field loosing focus on keydown and no text is entered. I'm using latest build of Select2 v4.0.0.

1. Clicked on select2 - list opened and input has focus
2. Started to search text (keydown) - input looses focus and no text appears
3. Strange, but on the same modal window, when Select2 is multiple type, it's working fine
4. Select2 is created on jqGrid dataInit event:

```js
dataInit: function (elem) {
$(elem).css({ width: "500px" }).select2({
 data: StacjeDlaIdZamPoc,
 allowClear: false,
 tags: false,
 minimumInputLength: 0,
 placeholder: "Wskaż stację",
 templateResult: function (repo) {
  if (repo.loading) {
   return repo.text;
  }
  return $(repo.text2);
 },
 templateSelection: function (repo) {
  return $(repo.text2);
 },
 minimumResultsForSearch: 5
}).on("select2:select", function(event) {
 var LWystapien = parseInt(event.params.data.LWystapien);
 $("#Wystapienie").val(1);
 $("#LWystapien").val(LWystapien);
 if (LWystapien > 1) {
  $("#Wystapienie").prop("disabled", false).spinner("enable");
 } else {
  $("#Wystapienie").prop("disabled", true).spinner("disable");
 }
});
}
```

As I wrote above I've tried fix for jQueryUI modal:

```js
if ($.ui && $.ui.dialog && $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction) {
    var ui_dialog_interaction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(e) {
     console.log(e);
        if ($( e.target ).closest('.select2-dropdown').length) { return true; }
        return ui_dialog_interaction.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

But this is not working on jqGrid modals.

It seems to work with Select2 full biuld and AttachContainer but I've noticed problems with oveflow: hidden :-(

Comment: I posted **UPDATED** part to my answer and to [your original post](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/59). I hope that it's the best solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the answer on [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/59) already, but because more people read steckoverflow I repeat here the main information.

jqGrid uses `jqModal.js` module by default for form editing. The modal `jqModal.js` register `keypress keydown mousedown` event handler on the `document` element (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jqmodal.js#L49)) which can block the pressed key and to set the focus on the first visible input element of the edit form (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jqmodal.js#L43)). One can solves the problem is two ways. The most simple way would be to

```js
$.fn.jqm = false;
```

which prevent usage of `jqModal.js` module. If one included jQuery UI js file then jqGrid will use jQuery UI modal in the case. It's the most simple way to solve the problem.

Alternatively one can add the class `jqmID1` (or `jqmID` appended with another index) to the container of select2. One can find the corresponding code example in [the comment](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/59#issuecomment-102177441). The demo works in Google Chrome at least. It demonstrates mostly the reason of the strange behavior of select2 inside of form editing. The recommended way would be just use jQuery UI modal or don't use `modal: true` option.

**UPDATED:** I thought about the problem and have found even better solution. I remind me that one had close problem with processing of mouse events in `jqModal.js` and I posted the fix many years ago which are included already in old version of jqGrid. The fix consist from testing **absolute** position of mouse cursor and if it was inside of the area of modal dialog then the mouse event was allowed.

So I had the idea to modify `jqModal.js` for making close tests for keyboard events too. I posted the corresponding changes to free jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/5267bc5a00d63d045e6c5405f19dc30061ed8926)) and now select2 have no problems. See http://jsfiddle.net/191no21j/13/.